# How to code an if(condition) loop that keeps generating a random matrix until it gets a close enough match in R

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, simulation

I am working with data simulation techniques that generate a random data set based off of a correlation matrix entered by the user. What I noticed after a while was that some randomly generated datasets were much closer to the actually correlation matrix than others. I wanted to create a function that 1) generates data sets, 2) compares correlation matrices with the original, and 3) repeats until there is a close enough match. Unfortunately, I was trained as a social scientist not a programmer and the "if/then" computer logic is harder for me to understand. Here is as far as I have gotten based on resources I found throughout the web:

```
    #Input Correlation Matrix
    sigma <- matrix(c(1.00, -0.03, 0.39, -0.05, -0.08,
                      -0.03, 1.00, 0.07, -0.23, -0.16,
                      0.39, 0.07, 1.00, -0.13, -0.29,
                      -0.05, -0.23, -0.13, 1.00, 0.34,
                      -0.08, -0.16 ,-0.29, 0.34, 1.00), nr=5, byrow=TRUE)
    rownames(sigma) <-c("Exercise", "Hardiness", "Fitness", "Stress", "Illness")
    colnames(sigma) <-c("Exercise", "Hardiness", "Fitness", "Stress", "Illness")

    #The Choleski Decomposition Random Data Generator
    N <- 373
    generate <-function(sigma) {
        L = chol(sigma)
        nvars = dim(L)[1]
        r = t(L) %*% matrix(rnorm(nvars*N), nrow=nvars, ncol=N)
        r = t(r)
        sample <- as.data.frame(r)}

    sample <- generate(sigma)

    # check if the empirical correlation is close to the theoretical sigma:
    correction <- function(sample) {
        zigma <- cor(sample)
        check <- all.equal(zigma, sigma, tolerance = .0025)
        if(check != "TRUE") {
        sample <- generate(sigma)
        correction(sample)
        }
        else
            return(check)
    }
```

And the error message I get upon running "correction(sample)" is:

```
    Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
```

What do you think is wrong with the if/else loop? Should I be trying to look at this problem from another perspective than loop logic?

Thank you all for your willingness to share your knowledge and expertise!

Comment: You're using the function `correction()` inside itself when the `if()` executes... therefore infinite recursions. I assume `sample` is meant to change with each iteration? At present, it just gets regenerated, since `generate(sigma)` will always return the same object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach of using a loop is fine, the problem is that you haven't got a loop -- you have a recursive call. You also don't need to write your own multivariate normal generator; `mvrnorm` in the `MASS` package does this already.

Try this.

```
library(MASS) # for mvrnorm
m <- rep(0, nrow(sigma))
repeat {
    samp <- mvrnorm(N, m, sigma) 
    z <- cor(samp)
    close_enough <- isTRUE(all.equal(z, sigma, tolerance=.0025))
    if (close_enough) break
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the good advice and for directing me to the proper package. The code you provided works well and is pretty efficient according to system.time(). (still takes forever though, haha).

Comment: Yeah, that's because a desired tolerance level of .0025 is actually very stringent, especially if N is only 373. If you bump up N to (say) 10 million, the loop will finish must faster.